# Contact Form 7 Few Fields Aren't Renders

Tags: wordpress, wamp, contact-form-7

I faced a little problem with contact form 7 that seems unusual. I found no solution searching on Google and Stackoverflow. I think the problem is basically with WAMP Server.

Same form works fine on Mac and live server, but when i pull the database to windows WAMP Sever it doesn't render few fields like text, email, url and tel.

[image: fields not rendered in frontend]

Even, I don't see those fields in contact form 7 admin. Please check attached screenshot.

[image: Few fields like text, email, url and tel aren't shown]

All fields are visible in below screenshot taken from working server.

[image: All fields are visible. Screenshot taken from working server]

Note: I have latest version WordPress, and Contact form 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this behavior once before, and I believe it was due to a a search and replace that I ran on the database when moving it over to my localhost. The search and replace actually screwed up the CF7 field data.

Did you do a search and replace on the site's domain name when you ported it over to WAMP server? If so, try doing the import again without doing the search and replace (you can add an entry in your windows hosts file to temporarily allow you to access the site on your machine at the 'live' address)

Comment: Thanks @Greg, I use WP DB Sync plugin to sync database between server and localhost. I use the plugin for a long while, but this issue if first.